# convert sensors data object to Byte array (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, sensors, sensormanager

I have a program that get all the sensors data from computer #1:

```
using Windows7.Sensors;

Sensor[] sensors = SensorManager.GetAllSensors();
foreach (Sensor sensor in sensors)
     sensor.DataUpdated += sensor_DataUpdated;
```

And in the DataUpdated function I want to send all the data to computer #2 using Sockets.
So I created a class that contain all the data:

```
[Serializable]
public class SensorData
{
    public Sensor Sensor { get; set; }
    public SensorDataReport SensorDataReport { get; set; }
    public SensorData()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the DataUpdated function:

```
static void sensor_DataUpdated(Sensor sensor, SensorDataReport dataReport)
{
     SensorData data = new SensorData(sensor, dataReport);
     socket.Send(data.ToByteArray()); // this 'ToByteArray()' is not a real function. this is what I am looking for
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to convert my class object to Byte Array.
when I tried to serialized it it failed because the SensorDataReport object cannot serialized.

Any idea how to do that??

Comment: Did you define [Serializable] on SensorDataReport too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
static void sensor_DataUpdated(Sensor sensor, SensorDataReport dataReport)
{
    SensorData data = new SensorData(sensor, dataReport);

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        socket.Send(data.ToByteArray());
    }
}
```